# Wrap text in <span> tag after X number of words (not counting blacklisted words)

Tags: php, replace, cpu-word, blacklist

I'm looking for a PHP function to insert a `<span>` tag after the 2 first words on a string but ignore some number of words.

For example, ignore the words: `One`, `Two`, `Three` and add a `<span>` after the 2 next words.

```
//"ONE" IS IGNORED, SPAN ADDED ON THE NEXT 2 WORDS
$string = "One example text bla bla bla";
$output = "One example text <span>bla bla bla</spa>";

//String added after the second word
$string = "Another example text bla bla bla";
$output = "Another example <span>text bla bla bla</spa>";
```

Comment: What code have you tried to achieve that goal?

Comment: take a look at [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php). you can use something like `$words = explode(" ",$string,3);`. Try to figure out how to go ahead from here and tell us if you need more help.

Comment: Guys you are misunderstanding his question, he knows how to explode but he doesn't not know how to take away strings he doesn't and of course he is looking for php function included in the language....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might seem longer but it is faster and highly configurable.

Okay, so what you have to is find word delimiter, which in this case is space (" ").

Next thing is to find 2 first words other than word from array e.g.: ("One","Two","Three",...).

Third thing is to unit the array of words into some logical string.

```
$string2Explode = "One great sentence is simply great."; //Also string
$stringExploded = explode(" ",$string2Explode); //array([0] => "One", [1]=> "great" etc.);
$preventedWords = array("One","Two","Three"); //Add prevented words here
$stringImploded = "";
$found = 0;
$count = 0;
while ($count !== count($stringExploded)) {
 $stringImploded .= $stringExploded[$count];
 if (!in_array($stringExploded[$count],$preventedWords)) {
  $found++;
 }

 $count++;
 if ((count($stringExploded)==$count)&&($found>=2)) {
  $stringImploded .= "</span>";
 } else {
    $stringImploded .= " ";
 }
  if ($found==2) {
   $stringImploded .= "<span>";
 }
}

//StringImploded also output.
```

Answer (score 0):

Explode string into an array, then iterate and insert new element, then join the array again:

```
<?php
$pos = 1;
$string  = "One example text bla bla bla";
$words = explode(" ", $string);
$new_array = array_slice($words, 0, $pos, true) +
    array($pos => "new word") +
    array_slice($words, $pos, count($words) - 1, true) ;
print_r($new_array);
$new_string = join(" ",$new_array);
echo $new_string;
?>
```

Comment: It does not prevent some strings!

Answer (score 0):

Match a sequence of visible characters followed by whitespace characters N times then forget them with `\K`, then match the rest of the string.  In the replacement, wrap the matched text in the HTML tag.  In my pattern, I have to double the curly brace around the variable, because inside of the double quoted pattern, the inner curly braces are interpreted as encapsulating the variable and the outer curly braces actually represent the quantifier markup for the regex engine.

The pattern gains a bit of complexity once you want to implement the blacklist of ignorable words.  Not only do you need to define a subpattern containing all disqualified words, you need to also need to use word boundaries to ensure only full words are matched and also accommodate the possibility of leading and trailing whitespaces.

Although the `$blacklist` array can be hardcoded with the English representations of numbers, I'll programmatically populate it with a native library.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/gm7G7))

```
$exemptWordCount = 2;

$f = new NumberFormatter("en", NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT);
$blacklist = array_map(fn($s) => $f->format($s), range(1, 10));
//var_export($blacklist);

$subpattern = '(?:\s*\b(?:' . implode('|', $blacklist) . ')\b\s*)*';

$string = "One example four text seVen bla bla bla";

echo preg_replace(
         "/(?:$subpattern\S+\s+){{$exemptWordCount}}$subpattern\K.+/i",
         '<span>$0</span>',
         $string
     );
// One example four text seVen <span>bla bla bla</span>
```